# Applescript a "Retry" button

Tags: macos, passwords, applescript, osx-mavericks

I'm coding an application with a password field:

```
set password1 to text returned of (display dialog "To continue please enter your special passcode below." buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 default answer "" cancel button 1 with hidden answer)
if the password1 is "passwordhere" then
display dialog "You have entered the password right!

    The right password was: passwordhere
    The entered password was: " & password1 buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 cancel button 1
else
if the password1 is "" then
set password1 to "Empty Passwordfield"
end if
display dialog "You have entered the password wrong!

    The right password was: ********
    The entered password was: " & password1 buttons {"Cancel", "Try Again"} default button 2 cancel button 1
end if
end
```

Now my question is: How do I make a "Try Again" button so it will return to the first display dialog? Is this possible? If not please say that in an answer.

Also a question: Is this also possible for just 2 normal dialogs? So that in the second dialog is a "Back" button? And if you press that button you'll return to the first dialog?

Thanks for reading,

Jort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider placing the password prompt/dialog in a applescript handler:

```
on get_password()
-- get password and return true if good, false if bad
end get_password
```

This way you can 're-call' the handler from anywhere else in your script as needed.

***Here is an example of your code that repeats the prompt for password as your question asked:***

```
local goodpassword, password1, tryagain, proceed

set goodpassword to false -- initial set
set tryagain to true -- initial set

on getpassword()
    return text returned of (display dialog "To continue please enter your special passcode below." buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 default answer "" cancel button 1 with hidden answer)
end getpassword


repeat while tryagain = true
    set proceed to true
    set password1 to getpassword() -- This calls the prompt for the first time

    if the password1 is "passwordhere" then
        set goodpassword to true
        set tryagain to false
        try
            display dialog "You have entered the password right!
    The right password was: passwordhere
    The entered password was: " & password1 buttons {"Cancel", "Continue"} default button 2 cancel button 1

        on error number -128
            set proceed to false
        end try

    else
        set goodpassword to false
        if the password1 is "" then
            set password1 to "Empty Passwordfield"
        end if
        try
            display dialog "You have entered the password wrong!

    The right password was: ********
    The entered password was: " & password1 buttons {"Cancel", "Try Again"} default button 2 cancel button 1
        on error number -128
            set tryagain to false
        end try
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand you :(. Could you please explain it to me in an example or edit my code and put your script/code in it? (I'm just new to applescript (6 days). (Also another question: Is it possible to make a return button between just normal dialogs? So that you will go back to a/the previous dialog using a button like "back" or something like that?) If you need my full script dont hesitate to ask me ;)! (This script is only a small part of my unfinished application.) PS: Thanks for the reply!

Comment: Thanks! Now I understand what you ment :)! Also thanks for editing the code! Now I am going to try the exact same thing with just normal dialogs! (I know I have to edit your code a bit to let it work with normal dialogs but thanks again :)!!!)